How can I store and query geospatial data in GridDB?
`I am working on a project that requires handling geospatial data, including coordinates (latitude and longitude) and performing spatial queries like proximity searches. I would like to store and query geospatial data using GridDB.
Here are some specific points I need help with:

How can I design a GridDB container to store geospatial data? Should I use specific data types for latitude and longitude?
Does GridDB support geospatial indexing or specialized functions for spatial queries (e.g., finding data points within a certain radius)?
Are there examples of using geospatial data in GridDB with Python or any other programming language?

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
from griddb_python import StoreFactory

factory = StoreFactory.get_instance()

gridstore = factory.get_store(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=10040,
    cluster_name="myCluster",
    user="admin",
    password="admin"
    )

container_info = {
    'name': 'geo_data',
    'column_info_list': [
        ("id", "STRING"),
        ("latitude", "DOUBLE"),
        ("longitude", "DOUBLE")
        ],
   'type': 'COLLECTION',
   'row_key': True
    }
container = gridstore.put_container(container_info)

row = ["1", 37.7749, -122.4194]  
container.put(row)

The container creation and data insertion seems to work, but I’m unsure how to efficiently query the data for geospatial use cases, like finding points within a specific distance from a given location.
I’d appreciate any guidance, examples, or best practices.
